# Use .cshtml pages in Composite C1 that aren't strict XHTML

Tags: c1-cms

I need to include some .cshtml / razor pages in a Composite C1 site that do not enforce strict XHTML / XML.

ie - any unclosed tags at the moment, for example, prevent the page loading.

A client requires this; is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap bad / unsafe markup in a CDATA section. Since the strict XML requirement is primarily needed inside the Composite C1 render engine and is typically not a concern for browsers, Composite C1 treat CDATA sections as "messy markup" which it will not parse, but just emit raw:

```
<div>
  <![CDATA[
    Bad & ugly HTML!<br>
  ]]>
</div>
```

It will pass through Composite C1 unhindered and come out as:

```
<div>
    Bad & ugly HTML!<br>
</div>
```

Above is quoted from http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Writing-XHTML

Here is a simple example with Razor syntax:

```
<div>
  <![CDATA[
    @{
      string unstructuredMarkup = "Bad & ugly HTML!<br>";
      @Html.Raw(unstructuredMarkup);
    }
  ]]>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - how will this work with razor content - can that be inside the CDATA section?

Comment: Yes, you can use all the features of Razor both outside and inside of the CDATA section. I've updated the answer so there is a simple Razor example also.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the ReturnType of your function to string (the default is XhtmlDocument). You do this by overriding the ReturnType property like this

```
@functions
{
   protected override Type FunctionReturnType
   {
      get { return typeof(string); }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - what are the relative advantages between this and the CDATA approach?!

Comment: that you don't need to fiddle with CDATA, plus there are still some cases where CDATA won't cut it, ie. i never got a ´<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->´ construct to work with CDATA.